# Upgrade from SQL 2005 EXPRESS to SQL 2008 EXPRESS

Tags: sql, database, size

I restored My database in SQL 2005 of size more than 4 GB but it creates problem when i save picture (image data) in database.i.e i can't save it.So i searched for that problem and came to know that SQL Express 2005 has database size limit of 4 GB.

i upgraded it to SQL EXPRESS 2008 and restored it to there.Still it has the same prblem means i can't able to save data..

So what may be the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to upgrade to 2008 R2 as 2008 still has the 4b limitation.

You can get 2008 R2 from here http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/

Comment: Thanks a lot dear friends for your valuable time.

I have installed SQL EXPRESS 2008 but it was not EXPRESS R2 version thats why its creating problem.

I came to know that thing when i was changing the initial size of database to 5500 MB.

Thankx.